# get ALL columns within the current week, converted from UTC to timezoneX

Tags: mysql

I try to form a query to return all columns but it's not working

```
SELECT * from mycalendar WHERE WEEK(datetime)=week(now());`
```

This returns everything however the date/time is stored in UTC in the database, so it will miss anything that could be in the same week but in UTC it's already the next week.

The following will return all the correct values adjusted for timezone, but I need all columns, instead I get both of the same columns.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(datetime, '+00:00', '-05:00') AS localdatetime,
(select localdatetime WHERE WEEK(localdatetime)=week(now())) FROM mycalendar;
```

Comment: Why don't you just `SELECT * FROM mycalendar WHERE WEEK(datetime) = WEEK(utc_timestamp())`?

Comment: @Mihe - thats the same result as first query - the issue is that if you are in PST Timezone and you enter a datetime in your localtime the DB will store it in UTC, so when you grab the week(now()) its in UTC time, a datetime say on 11pm PST Sunday will not show up in "current" week as the DB sees the time in UTC if that makes sense

Comment: ah, I understand you stored your local time without converting it to UTC, so basically you'd have to convert it to UTC. But in this case, you could convert now() to your timezone, which is more efficient because it needs to be done only once., e. g. `SELECT * FROM mycalender WHERE WEEK(datetime) = WEEK(CONVERT_TZ(now(), '+00:00', '-05:00'))`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mihe Thank you for the help that query worked fantastically for my use case!